# Where to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable in android project?

Tags: android, google-cloud-vision

I am developing an android application which requires use of google vision service provided by Google Cloud Platform.
For authentication, this uses a class **GoogleCredential** class, the code for which can be found here:

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/label-tutorial#authenticating

I need to set **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** variable as an environment variable pointing to a json file downloaded from another link, which is not important.

*The question is*:
When I set the environment variable using

```
Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.himanshu.myapplication/DtnPhotoShare-ff552ae2c96c.json");
    System.setProperty("**GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**",otherPath.toString());
```

*It gives me exception* :

> java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not
>   available. They are available if running on Google App Engine, Google
>   Compute Engine, or Google Cloud Shell. Otherwise, the environment
>   variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing
>   to a file defining the credentials.

*in line*

```
GoogleCredential credential =
                GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(VisionScopes.all());
```

All the code can be found in the link given above.

Comment: have u got solution for this

Answer (score -1):

You need service key on your disk and on linux based machine you can

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<path_to_service_credential_file>
```

Or alternatively add this to `~/.bashrc` (located in your home directory) file and source it so that this environment variable can be accessed by the library.